# What it going on behind the scenes in this code?

Tags: javascript

What is going on behind the scenes here for each script. Assuming that I will be `getsize()` alot, is there any difference between the code:

Code 1:

```
function Size (width, height)
{
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
}

function getSize()
{
    return new Size (0, 0);
}
```

Code 2

```
function getSize ()
{
    return {width: 0; height: 0};
}
```

I think they are equivalent both in all senses but just wanted to check.

Comment: The first returns a `Size` object the second return a 'standard' JS object??? What is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first code example you're returning a named object called Size, in the second code you're returning an anonymous javascript object. Thus you lose the Size objects constructor and prototype hindering you to extend all similar objects further.

Answer (score 1):

They're (essentially) equivalent **now**, but only until `Size`'s prototype changes. If that changes at any point in the future, your `{width: 0, height: 0}` will be incorrect, so it's probably better to use `return new Size(0, 0);`

The only real difference is that the `Size` object is an instance of a different object to a generic JS object:

```
var a = new Size(0,0);
var b = {width:0, height:0};
alert(a == b) // would be false even if JS didn't always say two objects are different (see comments)
```

Comment: The `==` note is a little bit confusing because "equal" objects are never equal in that sense. `{} !== {}`.